# Loop subdivision, certain areas converging towards degenerate geometry

Tags: c++, mesh, subdivision, float

I coded loop subdivision and ran it on a cube with triangle faces. I noticed this:

[image]

I am using doubles to represent my vertex positions, I am not 100% sure these are caused by floating point imprecisions, but since the general shape looks ok I am not sure what else it could be.

Any suggestions on how to find the cause? My linear algebra library is glm and I am coding this in C++.

Comment: Is it easy to try with f32 and see if things get worse?

Comment: They don't it looks the same with floats

Comment: You're not accidentally updating a source vertex position before it's been referenced by other vertex calculations are you?

Comment: @SimonF I don't think I am, I can go and check again, but the algorithm first calculates all the new positions, stores them in a container, and only once the calculation loop is finished do I start the loop to update the positions.

Also these artifacts only start to pop after the 4th ish iteration, the first 2-3 don't seem to exhibit any artifacts.